# How to match patterns in one sentence using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

Here are 2 examples,

```
1. I need to take this apple. I just finished the first one.

2. I need to get some sleep. apple is not working.
```

I want to match the text with `need` and `apple` in the same sentence.
By using `need.*apple` it will match both examples. But I want it works only for the first one. How do I change the code, or do we have other string methods in Python?

Comment: How is it matching the second one? `Apple` is capitalized in the second sentence. Are you doing case insensitive matching?

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/6v1KpY/2)? `(?:^|(?<=\.))(?=[^.\r\n]*\bneed\b)(?=[^.\r\n]*\bapple\b)[^.\r\n]*` with `i` (case-insensitive) modifier. Can sentences be multiline? Can words in the sentence include `.`? Something like `Mr. T is in need of an apple.` - what about plural or tenses: `needs`, `needed`, `apples`?

Comment: @Gillespie Hi I just revised my question. Actually it should be case insensitive.

Comment: You can also split on `.` and then check if contains `apple` and `need`. Do you need to match those words exactly or is a word like `pineapple` or `unneeded`, or `applesauce` also acceptable? If you need to match them exactly, after splitting on `.`, you can split on ` ` and then check to see if the array contains those words.

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted by @ctwheels concerning splitting on `.` and then testing to see if if it contains `apple` and `need` is a good one not requiring the use of regular expressions. I would first, however, split again on white space and then test these words against the resulting list to ensure you do not match against `applesauce`. But here is a regex solution:

```
import re

text = """I need to take this apple. I just finished the first one.
I need to get some sleep. apple is not working."""

regex = re.compile(r"""
    [^.]*           # match 0 or more non-period characters
    (
        \bneed\b    # match 'need' on a word boundary
        [^.]*       # match 0 or more non-period characters
        \bapple\b   # match 'apple' on a word boundary
      |             # or
        \bapple\b   # match 'apple' on a word boundary
        [^.]*       # match 0 or more non-period characters
        \bneed\b    # match 'need' on a word boundary
    )
    [^.]*           # match 0 or more non-period characters
    \.              # match a period
    """, flags=re.VERBOSE)

for m in regex.finditer(text):
    print(m.group(0))
```

Prints:

```
I need to take this apple.
```

The problem with both of these solutions is if the sentence contains a period whose usage is for purposes other than ending a sentence, such as `I need to take John Q. Public's apple.` In this case you need a more powerful mechanism for dividing the text up into sentences. Then the regex that operates against these sentences, of course, becomes simpler but splitting on white space still seems to make the most sense.